# How to remove some characters from a String

Tags: java

I am getting a date in this format:

```
2011-05-23 6:05:00
```

How can I obtain only 2011-05-23 from this string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import java.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class StringApp {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String oldDate = "2011-05-23 6:05:00";
        String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            Calendar cl = Calendar.getInstance();
            cl.setTime(sdf.parse(oldDate));
            String newDate = sdf.format(cl.getTime());
            System.out.println(newDate);
        } 
        catch (ParseException ex) { 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You *could* just take the index of the first space and use `substring`:

```
int firstSpace = text.indexOf(' ');
if (firstSpace != -1)
{
    String truncated = text.substring(0, firstSpace);
    // Use the truncated version
}
```

You'd need to work out what you wanted to do if there weren't any spaces.

However, if it's meant to be a valid date/time in a particular format and you know the format, I would parse it *in* that format, and then only *use* the date component. [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) makes it very easy to take just the date part - as well as being a generally better API.

EDIT: If you mean you've already *got* a `Date` object and you're trying to format it in a particular way, then `SimpleDateFormat` is your friend in the Java API - but again, I'd recommend using Joda Time and its `DateTimeFormatter` class:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
String text = formatter.print(date);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [SimpleDateFormat](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/web/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd k:m:s", locale);
Date date;

try {
  date = (Date)parser.parse("2011-05-23 6:05:00");
} catch (ParseException e) {
}

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
s = formatter.format(date);
```

Also:

- http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/FormatDate.html

Answer (score 1):

*Standard way* would be use of [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

You can also accomplish it using `String` operation as follows

```
String result = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
String arg="2011-05-23 6:05:00";
String str=arg.substring(0,arg.indexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well an ineffective, but brute force method would be to say

```
String s = "2011-05-23 6:05:00";
String t = s.substring(0,s.length-7);
```

Or whatever the case should be

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "2011-05-23 6:05:00"
str = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way :

String str="2011-05-23 6:05:00";
str =str.subString(0,10);

Answer (score 0):

Lots of answers, but no one had used regexp so far, so I just had to post an answer with regexp.

```
String date = "2011-05-23 6:05:00";
System.out.println(date.replaceFirst("\\s.*", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer which uses a regex.

```
String dateTime = "2011-05-23 6:05:00";
String date = dateTime.split(" ")[0];
```